# "Render mathematics" is inactive in Inkscape

Tags: latex, inkscape

I recently installed Inkscape on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and I'd like to use the builtin latex support, but when I go to *Extensions > Render > Mathematics > pdflatex*, the button is grey, so clicking triggers no event.

I installed texlive using the ctan installer and not via `apt`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My inkscape version was installed using snap, so I replaced it with an apt install:

Remove the snap install :
`sudo snap remove inkscape`
Then install inkscape version 1.0 or higher :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inkscape
```

Be sure to include the path to latex in your .bashrc file, and run inkscape from the command line : when you run inkscape from the Dock, it's harder to control the value of the PATH system variable.

Comment: The only thing that bugs me still with this solution is that I have to launch inkscape from a Terminal : indeed the path to latex is configured in my .bashrc, and gnome's launcher ignores my .bashrc script.

Comment: can you also specify running Inkscape from the terminal in your main answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [textext](https://textext.github.io/textext/), which is not bundled in inkscape by default. It works for me.